# Default angular input field value after second delete

Tags: angular, forms, ngmodel

I have a simple input with `ngModel`.

HTML:

```html
    <input type="number" min="0" [ngModel]=testField (ngModelChange) = setValue($event)>
    <p>{{testField}}</p>
```

TS:

```typescript
    testField = 5;

    setValue(value: number): void {
     if (value) {
       this.testField = value;
     } else {
       this.testField = 0;
     }
    }
```

When I delete value from input for the first time it set input value to 0 as expected, but if I delete this 0, input field stay empty. How can I set its value to 0 anyway, after deleting 0 second time ?

StackBlitz: [click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pw9c1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can watch for the `keyup` event and if the $event.target.value is === '', set value to 0.

```typescript
  testField = 5;
  keepValueZero = $event => {
    if ($event.target.value === "") {
      $event.target.value = 0;
    }
  };
  setValue(value: number): void {
    if (value) {
      this.testField = value;
    } else {
      this.testField = 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" [ngModel]=testField (ngModelChange) = setValue($event) (keyup)='keepValueZero($event)'>
<p>{{testField}}</p>
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nohqsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful. Changed to blur, and it works as I want. Sorry, my upvote is not showing, but that a plus to karma for you. Have any ideas why second time 0 is not showing ?